# Setting up DNS server for multiple networks at once using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I am using this script to set my DNS and toggle between the DNS servers:

```
$nic = get-wmiobject win32_networkadapterconfiguration | where {$_.IPEnabled -eq $true -and $_.DHCPEnabled -eq $true}

foreach($n in $nic){

    if($nic.DNSserverSearchOrder -eq "172.xxxxxxxx")
    {
        $servers = "8.8.8.8","8.8.4.4"
        $nic.SetDNSServerSearchOrder($servers)
    }
    else
    {
        $servers = "172.xxxxxxxx","172.xxxxxxxx"
        $nic.SetDNSServerSearchorder($servers)
    }
}
```

Now, This script works fine if I am connected to one network. If I am connected to multiple network, this throws error:

> "Method Invocation failed because [system.object[]] doesnt contain a method names 'setDNSsearchorder'".

Now if this works for one network, and for two networks I am looping them, why is this not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looping through the NICs with `foreach($n in $nic)`, but then you are running methods on `$nic`.  You need to run the methods on `$n`, because when there are multiple NICs, `$nic` will be an array ([system.object[]]).

```
foreach($n in $nic){
    if($n.DNSserverSearchOrder -eq "172.xxxxxxxx")
    {
        $servers = "8.8.8.8","8.8.4.4"
        $n.SetDNSServerSearchOrder($servers)
    }
    else
    {
        $servers = "172.xxxxxxxx","172.xxxxxxxx"
        $n.SetDNSServerSearchorder($servers)
    }
}
```

If there is only one NIC, `$nic` will be the object type that supports the method instead of an array of those objects, which is why it works when there is only one NIC.

Comment: Such a shame. :( Basic coding error. The closer i looked , the less i saw. :(